# How to translate a vb.net generic class to c#?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface

I have this .NET solution where I need to get some old vb.net projects and convert them into new c# ones.
I stuck with one particular interface and need some help. This the vb.net signature:

```
Public Interface SomeInterface(Of T as Class)
    Inherits IDisposable

...
End Interface
```

How do I write this in c#?

Comment: Actually, I don't think that this is a bad question at all.  C#'s relative lack of keywords makes it suprisingly hard to figure stuff like this out when you are coming from a keyword-heavy language like VB, there's no clear keyword to Google.  And when you look at all of the doc, it's far from obvious that one of those strange extra lexemes (like `:`) is actually the inheritance operator/keyword that you've been trying to find.  And most folks don't know about the conversion sites until someone mentions it.

Comment: @RBarryYoung If that's too much for you then you can simply google "C# generic interface" and get [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwtft8ak(v=vs.80).aspx) which has everything he needs easily accessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public interface SomeInterface<T> : IDisposable where T : class
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface SomeInterface<T> : IDisposable 
  where T : class
{
}
```

`SomeInterface(Of T as Class)` becomes a C# generic `SomeInterface<T>`, and a C# constraint `where T : class`.

The `Inherits IDisposable` in C# is just `: IDisposable`.

The rest is just an issue of C# using lower case for its keywords.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I'm not experienced in c# and was trying - public interface SomeInterface<T> where T : class : IDisposable - which obviously wasn't working.

Comment: Downvoter: Voting "not useful" without leaving a comment is not very useful either.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply include the class in the project as is. I have at least one VB.Net project that uses a C# resource.

Comment: And I did, to get it working. But the requirements are to translate everything to c#

Comment: I see, sorry about that.

Answer (score -1):

```
public interface SomeInterface<T> :IDisposable where T:class
{
}
```

Comment: yeah I was in the middle of editing it

Comment: You shouldn't post answers until they are done and actually answer the question.  Posting wrong and incomplete answers in an attempt to get an earlier timestamp is not appropriate behavior.

Comment: it wasn't to get timestamp anyway